# spplot() - ploting two graphs with the same color scale and correcting the position of tick marks

Tags: r, scale, colorbar, r-sp

I'm having a problem with the color bar (or color ramp palette) in spplot (adehabitatHR package). I'm want to plot two graphs in the same window using spplot and I also want that the color bar has the same scale for both graphs (just one bar for both graphs). If that is not possible - or too complicated, since I'm new in R language - I wanna set an equal number of tick marks in the bar for both graphs. I had setted this already, but they are in different positions in the color bar - it would make more sense if i have at least one tick mark at lowest value of the bar, one in the middle, and other in the highest valeu. But when I use the `colorkey=list(tick.number=3)` argument it doesn't allow me to choose where I want the tick marks. How can I do that?

Here is part of my code.

```
####loading packages....
library("adehabitatHR")
library(latticeExtra)
###... and data
area.total.mari<- read.table("mari.total.txt")
area.total.mari2<- SpatialPoints(area.total.mari)
area.total.mari.mpc=mcp(area.total.mari2)
dry.mari<- read.table("pontos meses seca.txt")
dry.mari1<- SpatialPoints(dry.mari)
dry.mari1.mpc=mcp(dry.mari1)

###color used in the graphs
mycolor2=gray(16:0/16)

##generating kernels and spplot's
ks<-kernelUD(seca.mari1, grid=300, extent=0.2)
ps<-spplot(ks, col.regions=mycolor2,colorkey=list(tick.number=3),
    scales=list(draw=T))+
    layer(sp.polygons(area.total.mari.mpc))

kc<-kernelUD(chuva.mari1, grid=300, extent=0.35)
pc<-spplot(kc,col.regions=mycolor2,colorkey=list(tick.number=3),
    scales=list(draw=T)))+
    layer(sp.polygons(area.total.mari.mpc))

###printing graphs
######## Tick marks are messed up :/
print(ps, position=c(0,0,.5,1),more=T)
print(pc, position=c(0.5,0,1,1))
```

Here is the graph generated with this code:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/129526227@N02/16316924041/

Note the problem with the tick marks: the lowest value ("0") is ok, but I can't place the another value in the highest!

This is an example with the "meuse" data set:

```
library(sp) 
library(lattice)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(latticeExtra)
data(meuse) 
coordenadas<-data.frame(meuse$x,meuse$y)
attach(coordenadas)
coord.sp.pt<- SpatialPoints(coordenadas)
coord.sp.pt.mpc=mcp(coord.sp.pt)
mycolor=gray(0:12/12)
coord.sp.ud<-kernelUD(coord.sp.pt, grid=300, extent=0.1)
coord.printing<-spplot(coord.sp.ud, col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","gray","black"))
        ,colorkey=list(tick.number=2),scales=list(draw=T))+
    layer(sp.polygons(coord.sp.pt.mpc))
print(coord.printing)
```

Thanks in advance folkes

Comment: Can you please post your data, or create a MWE with a reduced data set?

Comment: Hey **rmccloskey** thanks for answering. I just edited the question including a mwe. Is that right?

Comment: **rmccloskey**, I could solve the problem - it wasn't the "right" way, but it worked. Basically, i discovered the highest value of my graph, and added it on the `colorkey` argument, something like: `colorkey=list(labels=list(at=XXXX,lables=YYY)`.